# Is there a way to put help link closer to apex:inputField in a pageBlockSection

Tags: visualforce, apexinputfield, apexpage

My Visualforce page screenshot looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, Find endpoint in Vision6 is a help link for the endpoint field, so I would like to make it closer to the inputField. However, I do find it very hard... My current visualforce code looks like this:

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Connect Vision6">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Connect Your Vision6 account" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!conn.Name}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!conn.End_point__c}" style="width: 300px"/>
            <a href="http://www.vision6.com.au/integration/api_keys/">Find Endpoint in Vision6</a>  
            <apex:inputField value="{!conn.Api_Key_Encrypted__c}" style="width: 300px"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!conn.Auto_Sync__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!conn.is_Active__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveConnection}" value="{!$Label.Save_Connection}"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

I have already used a walk around here by making the pageBlockSection two columns and fill the empty space with empty `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>`. And now it looks like this. I have tried the wrap the link and inputField in a pageBlockSectionItem but it still doesn't work since it won't show the label of the inputField anymore. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in an outputPanel

```
<apex:outPutPanel layout="inline">

<apex:inputField value="{!conn.End_point__c}" style="width: 300px"/>
            <a href="http://www.vision6.com.au/integration/api_keys/">Find Endpoint in Vision6</a>

</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you for this and I agree it is kind of working. However, I need to add the label myself and do the styling of the inputField. Considering the window can be resized, it is not easy to align the labels and inputFields with others in the pageBlockSection. How can I achieve this?

Comment: tradeoffs have to be taken when using the page block table. I have since stopped using them in favor of other frameworks. Someone may have a good answer for you that covers all the bases

Comment: I understand. I don't like it as well. But my company wants our package to look Salesforcy with every Salesforce version. So I guess using that is the only option.